# Rails: Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I integrated omniauth-facebook using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview. But I am getting error of :

```
Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials".
```

I have devise installed. When i click on facebook sign in link, it redirects me to facebook login. When i enter my details, it comes back to devise sign and gives above error. I checked the solution for "Invalid credentials" on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview and my app is header set for App Type = Web. Not getting why it is not working.

Also my app is live but yet to approve from facebook. But i don't think it is related to this error. Following are the things i did for omniauth-facebook:

Gemfile contains:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
```

In user model, added:

```
devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
attr_accessible :provider, :uid

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                      )
   end
 user
 end
```

devise.rb

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", :scope => "offline_access, email"
```

Link for facebook sign_in:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

route.rb:

devise_for :user, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }

Omniauth controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
   end
 end
```

Can anybody help in this?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but might it be that you have a space before email on your omniauth scope?
I had the same error due to a typo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176208/rails-could-not-authenticate-you-from-facebook-because-invalid-credentials)

Comment: This has been flagged as a duplicate of an identical question you posted that had more info. In the future if you have additional info to add to a question, please edit the existing question instead of starting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your browser cookies. sometimes omniauth won't work just because you have to delete your browser cookies.

an other thing could be that the version isn't right.

> The problem seems to be the dependencies. At 1.4.0 it requires
>   omniauth-oauth2 1.0.3, and at 1.4.1 it required omniauth-oauth 1.1.x

as seen here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/276

Comment: versions are omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.2) for omniauth-facebook (1.4.0). Is it ok or it should be 1.0.3?

Comment: just try to update all as high as possible. that could work. but i'm not sure.

Comment: cleared the cookies and I tried to upgrade using sudo gem install omniauth-oauth2 --version 1.0.3. But it is still 1.0.2. Getting same error.

Comment: the newest version of omniauth is 1.1.4, put this in your gemfile: gem "omniauth", "~> 1.1.4" and run bundle install.

Comment: the newest version of omniauth-oauth is 1.0.1 put this in your gemfile: gem "omniauth-oauth", "~> 1.0.1" and run bundle install.

Comment: gem "omniauth-oauth", "~> 1.0.1" or gem "omniauth-oauth2", "~> 1.0.1"

Comment: sorry forget those. i missed the 2. put this in your gemfile: gem "omniauth-oauth2", "~> 1.1.1" that's the current version :D that should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28719/discussion-between-user2206724-and-kees-sonnema)

Comment: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure